# Javascript fires on page refresh

Tags: javascript

Why does javascript fire on a page refresh from the browser?

I have a page that has a lot of javascript and ajax requests; when I hit refresh, I'll see some console.log warnings flash and what appears to be the start of some of my functions. Then, the page reloads normally.

I'm using Chrome.

Update:

What I'm talking about is the event before the page comes back. So, when a user hits refresh, I see some console messages and then the page refreshes and operates as expected. Thanks for your inputs on this.

Order of events:

1. Page loads as normal
2. User hits refresh
3. I see some console warnings
4. Page loads as normal

What is happening that the console messages would show up? I assumed that hitting 'refresh' would be just like visiting a page for the first time but clearly that's not the case if the console is throwing some messages. What's going on right after you click 'refresh' that continues to run through the page before it refreshes?

Comment: How about some code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Because a refresh is basically exactly the same as first landing on a page. It's a "new" page, even if it's just the same address as before, so all the JS runs as if it was a new page. Refreshing will also trigger any onbeforeunload handlers and then the onload stuff when the refresh completes.

Comment: That's how it works: the browser will execute JavaScript each and every time the page is refreshed. If you mean something else, please edit your question and explain better.

Comment: Baszz; it's not really a problem, just a question.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  console.log('Just before page leaves');
  // if you return a string, it gets displayd in a confirmation dialog
  // so the user can cancel the 'refresh'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What we normally call "refresh" is nothing but a page loading.

So when a user refresh a page, the page is being loaded again, exactly like the first time it's loaded.

If you have some scripts running on your first page load, they will get executed on every refresh too.

Comment: Jose, I'm referring to the events firing prior to the refresh. So, you hit refresh, then some console warnings come through and THEN the page refreshes.